# postgres: query percentage execution

Tags: sql, postgresql

im new using postgres
Im launching a query on my develop envirnment that takes too much time.
Please does anyone knows, how to show the query percentage of execution.

Thank you,

Comment: What do you mean by percentage? In terms of I/O resources, processed rows, returned rows, total execution time?

Comment: i want to saw the query progress. @TheImpaler

Comment: time left to finish the execution. @TheImpaler

Comment: For all queries -- maybe excluding only the most simple ones -- the engine doesn't know the total execution time of it.

Comment: You cannot get such an estimate in PostgreSQL.

Comment: @TheImpaler but it knows at least that the query has executed 70% . Or that it still have 30% of rows to execute?.

Comment: @TheImpaler  thank you guys, but i have query that is running during 3 hours. and don"t know what is better to wait or to kill the process. What do you propose? please?

Comment: @Laurenz Albe do you see what i mean. ?? please.

Comment: No, it doesn't know the query has executed 70% of it. The engine is just executing the execution plan tree. Maybe it's deep walking the nodes, or maybe at the top. For example, the engine doesn't know how many rows are still left to process.

Comment: There are many ways of improving the speed of a query. Maybe if you posted another question with the specifics of the slow query we can help you making it faster.

Comment: Your request is reasonable, but PostgreSQL does not have such a functionality. An expert could attach a debugger to the backend and investigate, but that's all.